# XML generation using XSD file and libxml2

Tags: c, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, libxml2

I need to generate an xml file related to his xsd with libxml2.
I already know how to work with libxml2:

```
xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr xsdParserPtr = NULL;
xmlSchemaPtr xsdSchemaPtr = NULL;
xmlSchemaValidCtxtPtr xsdValidPtr = NULL;

xsdParserPtr = xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt(xsdPath);
xsdSchemaPtr = xmlSchemaParse(xsdParserPtr);
xsdValidPtr = xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt(xsdSchemaPtr);
```

Now I would like to generate the xml file
I try to use the xmlSchemaPtr struct that is an `_xmlSchema` sctruct defined in xmlschemas.h that have inside a struct xmlDocPtr doc but no one of the function that I check seems to be ok.ES:

```
xmlNode *root_element = NULL;
root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(xsdSchemaPtr->doc);...
```

Is it possible or I need to generate a new XML file build it and afterwards compare it with his XSD with `xmlSchemaValidateDoc` func?

Thank you in advance.